# Pagination not working after adding custom column & conditions based on the new column

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, pagination

I'm basically trying to implement pagination after inserting a new column using **addSelect()**
and a where condition based on this new column.
Below is the code:

```
$lattitude = $request->lattitude != '' ? $request->lattitude : auth()->user()->details->lattitude;
$longitude = $request->longitude != '' ? $request->longitude : auth()->user()->details->longitude;
$distance = $request->distance;

$query = Facility::query();
$query = $query->AddLocationDistance($lattitude, $longitude);
$query = $query->where('location_distance', '<', $distance);
return $query->paginate(10);
```

Here AddLocationDistance is a scope in the model,

```
public function scopeAddLocationDistance($query, $lattitude, $longitude)
{
    return $query->addSelect(
        DB::Raw('FORMAT(( 6367 * acos( cos( radians(' . $lattitude . ') ) * cos( radians( lattitude ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(' . $longitude . ') ) + sin( radians(' . $lattitude . ') ) * sin( radians( lattitude ) ) ) ),1) AS location_distance')
    );
}
```

The above code works for **get()** but I cannot use **paginate()**. I get this error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'location_distance' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `facilities` where location_distance < 1000)
```

What should I do to fix the above problem? Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a laravel package that takes care of this problem.

Its fixed by Taylor Otwell in Laravel version 7.10 only.
So use this package.
[Package](https://github.com/justbetter/laravel-pagination-with-havings)